# What is my best option for submitting code to github from within an NTLM firewall?

Tags: git, proxy, github, ntlm

I'm thinking of using github to more nicely organise some of my code projects (i'm on a mission to implement all the major crypto algorithms in c, c#, js, golang, and ruby - but that's another story...).

But i'm stuck behind an NTLM firewall. Any suggestions for how i'd check code in? Some kind of configuration of tortoisegit and ntlmaps to work through the firewall? I'd even be happy to upload code through a web form, although i don't think github works that way.

Thanks all

Comment: It's worth noting that [Github now offers online editing of code](https://github.com/blog/905-edit-like-an-ace).

Answer (score 1):

Use the http protocol.

Comment: That only seems to allow me to pull code (clone), it won't allow me to push over http (or at least i can't figure it out).
Ref: http://github.com/blog/642-smart-http-support

Answer (score 1):

Just got a (super-quick!) reply from the github support team, they recommend the following:

http://help.github.com/firewalls-and-proxies/
Try smart-http first, it's likely to have the best results for the least effort.

Answer (score 0):

Ok had no luck with smart-http, but figured it out, hopefully someone else will find this useful:

- Unzip msysgit to c:\msysgit (i used the PortableGit-1.7.0.2-preview20100309.7z version)
- Install and run NTLMAPS (http://ntlmaps.sourceforge.net/)
- Edit the 'C:\msysgit\etc\gitconfig' file and add the following line right after the [http] line:

  proxy = localhost:5865
- Install TortoiseGit
- Configure TortoiseGit to use "C:\msysgit\bin" as the path for msysgit
- Use the "http://" git links only